# Opening Existing Django Project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I've been using Jetbrains Pycharm for years, but lately the performance has been getting abysmal. I'd like to give Visual Studio a shot.

So I cloned my main repo, through VS, and tried to setup a "Solution". It doesn't seem to recognize my project. In Pycharm I could just clone any old repo, open the folder and then select the interpreter/env I wanted to run it in. I've kinda got it working by creating a django project in VS and then loading all my files in, but that doesn't seem right or viable.

Any tips on how to setup/create a "Solution" for a cloned django project?

[image: Screenshot of My Issue]

Comment: I am not putting this as an answer because I cannot confirm it (not working with my project): the only guidance from MS is [to create a new project from existing code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/quickstart-01-python-in-visual-studio-project-from-existing-code). I definitely recommend trying this on a copy of the directory if you do this, there likely will be errors due to path and other issues, and if I get it working will add an answer but for now it really is the only guidance. :\

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio create a new project and select `Python` -> `From Existing Python code`.
For `Location` choose the folder of your existing Django project.

Clicking `Ok` will open the "Create New Project from Existing Python Code Wizard" screen.
Your existing folder should already be entered, so click `Next`.

On the next screen I kept the `Python interpreter` settings at `default` (use global default). Click `Next`.

Then, be sure to check the box `Customize Project Type` and select `Django Web Project`.

Click `Finish`.

[Source](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/visual-studio-python-importing-existing-project/)

Answer (score 3):

To add to VME's question, this is a screenshot from VS2017:

[image: VS2017 Python existing]

Make sure to select Python itself rather than any of the items below (Web etc).